# PHP require_once in back

Tags: php, require-once

I have one problem in my code and i dont know how to fix.

I have FILES like that:

**ROOT->INCLUDES - inc_files.php**

AND NEW FILE

**ROOT->INCLUDES->STRANICE - blog.class.php**

How can i use require_once in blog.class.php to include inc_files.php ?

My code (blog.class.php)

```
require_once("./inc_files.php");
```

ALL TRYS

```
require_once("../inc_files.php"); 
require_once(".../inc_files.php");
```

And more... 
Please help!

Comment: Please don't YELL. You clearly already know how to use Markdown. That's all that you need. (Normally I would edit your question myself, but I'm not totally sure what it's supposed to say…)

Comment: Actually, you can just test them, since you have written them... Also, a hint is to use [`realpath`](//php.net/realpath) to find out which file you have pointed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using paths relative to your current PHP file?

In your `root/includes/stranice/blog.class.php`:

```
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . "/inc_files.php");
```

Comment: Did you fix my typo with the capital F?

Comment: They dont have capital F

Comment: Did you mean "not work" or "now work"? Also, can you try `echo basename(dirname(__DIR__) . "/inc_files.php");` to see what this path points to? My answer now should be correct. You probably have copied [my typo](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39548828/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/inc_files.php');
```

Comment: From my personal experience, this method becomes a disaster when I move my site into a subdirectory in a friend's website because I needed to host it on a friend's machine (while my own host was down). Probably not a problem with most people though.

Comment: I need some pernament solved because if i change some directory i need manual change code..

Comment: Work - > require_once('./includes/inc_files.php');
But why?

Comment: Because your include path is set to your root path? Is your script run from a file at the document root directly?

Comment: And if you change your files' location you will always have to change the code manually. The only exception would be if you used @PEMapModder's code and then moved the whole `includes` folder.